# Mix html and code asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to join two strings but I want them to be divided by a break line.

This is my code:

```
<td>@(string.Join("<br /> ", report.TimeReportProjects.Select(x => x.Project.ProjectName)))</td>
<td>@(string.Join("<br /> ", report.TimeReportProjects.Select(x => x.Description.Shorten(35))))</td>
<td>@(data.StartHour + ":" + data.StartMinute.ToString("00") + " - " + data.EndHour + ":" + data.EndMinute.ToString("00"))</td>
<td>@(Math.Floor(hours) + ":" + TimeSpan.FromHours(hours).Minutes.ToString("00"))</td>
```

The "br/>" tag will just be read as a string which is not to strange I assume, I know if i want to mix html code in a code block I should use @: but I am not sure how to use that in this case.

Comment: You can use @Html.Raw helper.

Comment: Returns markup that is not HTML encoded. Dosen't that mean it will still return my "<br />" as "<br />"?

Comment: It means that if your string is not html-encoded it will be rendered as actual HTML. In your case - break line will be inserted.

Comment: I see, that did work. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`Html.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) method that should help you. It can be applied like so:

```
<td>@Html.Raw(string.Join("<br />", report.TimeReportProjects.Select(x => x.Project.ProjectName)))</td>
```